# Facial hair and razor

Tags: hadith

I wanted to know wether it is haram for a women to use a razor to shave facial hair. And if it is  not where does it say in hadith ir the quran

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not Haram. It's surely allowed to get rid of facial hairs for women whatever way they want.